# Need to execute shell script from webapp and display console output in page

Tags: java, web-applications, shellexecute

I am looking for java examples or library that will help me integrate this into a Struts2/Spring application.  Many build systems such as Luntbuild or Hudson have this functionality, I thought I would ask if any one  knows of a standalone example before I attempted to dig it out of one of those. I glanced at Quartz job scheduling framework also, but I haven't found the UI hooks yet. Do I just need to read from a file with a JSP include?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you are trying to do, this is one way in Java.  This executes the ls command and then captures the shell output and writes it back to System.out.

```
public class TestShell {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
                String cmd = "ls\n";
                Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
                p.waitFor();
                BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
                while(r.ready()) {
                    System.out.println(r.readLine());
                }

        }
        catch (Throwable t)
                {
                t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you could also add:

BufferedReader r2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
while(r2.ready()) {
    System.out.println(r2.readLine());
}

To get standard error output too

Comment: How important is the p.waitFor()?

Comment: Supposedly it waits for the process to exit.  I'm not sure if you can read before that time or not.  I ultimately did not need the shell output for what I was doing so I didn't explore it fully.  I do know that running under windows trying to do the same thing I had timing issues

Comment: (cont.'d) with the shell closing and I would not get a full directory listing.