# How to get properties of a local file on C: drive with JSP or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, file, jsp, properties

I'm developing a web app using JSP/Javascript, it lets user upload a local fonts file, how to get the font Title from the font's file property in the JSP page, with Java or Javascript ?

[image]

See details from the attached picture, I want to get the value of the "Title" which is : A.C.M.E Explosive Bold

I want to show user the info before they actually hit the submit button and upload it.
Yes, it needs to happen on the user side and looks like the following :

[image]

Comment: will this help .. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176615.aspx :) not a java code but can be worked on .

Comment: So, you have a HTML5 FileReader to get the font file the user wants to upload? Or what do you want to happen clientside (in JS)?

Comment: @Ashish Gupta : Yes, that's what I want, but I need it in JSP/Javascript/Struts environment, how to do it ?

Comment: write a shell script . upload it in your server Read it through java code. Read the result http://stackoverflow.com/a/428989/1085285  Another one is :: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10810943/1085285

Comment: @Frank this can be done with HTML5.  See my demo here: http://fontificate.samlecuyer.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a library to do this.  See an example [here](http://fontificate.samlecuyer.com/).  The file you'll want to look at in particular is fontificate.js, as well as the index.html inline scripts.  Calabash.js is another library I wrote for promises and can be for the most part ignored (as long as it's still included).

Comment: Yes, but OP wants do perform this in the browser.

Comment: OP got me curious enough to go home and write a library to do this.

Comment: If you take a look at the loop that's pulling out each string and concatenating it with it's title, you can filter by nameID === 4.  Then you can ignore basically everything else.

Comment: Unfortunately, this app won't ever work in IE9 because it uses newer APIs that Microsoft hasn't implemented in their browsers.

Comment: My app has to support IE8,9 and Firefox.

Comment: Works here with current Firefox, Chrome, and Opera. Safari and IE8 say "Sorry, your browser doesn't support Files"

Comment: @saml : I found that for IE9, I can probably use something like this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12530488/how-to-get-all-the-attributes-of-a-file [Maybe detect which browser first then handle accordingly ? But I'm still having trouble getting the "Title" property from your code, any sample code ? Thanks ! ]

Comment: Yes, although it only works in Firefox, but there is nothing better than this. thanks !

Answer (score -1):

I believe this is not possible with JSP or JavaScript. Security constraints do not allow you to access local files. HTML's `<input type="file"` also cannot be intercepted by your code, thus I see only one chance: A Java Applet could do the trick, provided the user has trusted it. Flash might work as well, but I don't know about that.