# How to get all the attributes of a file?

Tags: javascript, file, properties

I use the following lines in Javascript to get a file's attribute :

```
  var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
  var fileObj = fso.GetFile("C:\ACME_Explosive_Bold.ttf");  
  alert('File Attribute: '+fileObj.Attributes);
```

In IE9, it shows a warning window and then says : "File Attribute: 32", that's not I want, what I'd like to see is the "Title" property of this file, as shown in the attached picture, how can I get it ? I tried alert('File Attribute: '+fileObj.Attributes[10]); but didn't work.

The number "10" is for Title, see here : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176615.aspx

[image]

Comment: fileObj.Attributes refers to regular file attributes (read-only etc); it looks like you want an extended property instead. The page you linked to shows how to get hold of those via a Shell.Application object.

Comment: @Ian : Thanks for the info, so how to get it from JSP/Javascript page ?

Comment: This page has a similar(ish) example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787870(v=vs.85).aspx. BTW getting IE to run this kind of code would probably require significant changes to default security settings (if it runs at all)...